# Tomcat Error 500 on servlet: "Cannot forward after response has been"

Tags: java, servlets, runtime-error

Tomcat shows me an Error 500 when I'm trying to validate request parameters.

Stacktrace:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Cannot forward after response has been 
type Exception 
message Cannot forward after response has been 
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from 
fulfilling this request. exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
```

Here is piece of my servlet (there is no PrintWriter.flash or anything like that).

This code is in the beginning of the servlet.  Why do I get an `IllegalArgumentException` on an "already commited" response?

```
String login = req.getParameter("login");
String password = req.getParameter("password");

if (login.length() == 0 || password.length() == 0) {
    req.setAttribute("wrong", "Your login or password is empty");

    RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/index.jsp");
    rd.forward(req, resp);
}
```

Comment: No such code, only plain jstl:
<c:if test="${ wrong != null }">
<b><span style="color:#ff0000"> 
<c:out value="${wrong}"/>
</span></b>
</c:if>

+ html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return` after Dispatch the page.That will resolve your exception.

```
    RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/index.jsp");
    rd.forward(req, resp);
    return;
```

**REASON:**

When you '`forward`' or '`include`', the same `request` and `response` is passed to that resource. If you close the output stream, it cannot be used by the `JSP` to return the data. As soon as any data gets written to the `client`, the response is already `committed`

Comment: -1 for [plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/ive-been-accused-of-plagiarism-what-do-i-do)

Comment: @BalusC sir is it necessary to put outside content also?? I am putting only SO links .